# Queue in c++ push and front

Tags: c++, stl, queue

the code is the answer to a problem in codeforces so i only need what is the programming mistake in the code..the queue make a problem he doesn't push the elements or maybe the problem in the output..can you help me?

When i run it..they print a random numbers instead of the numbers which i push them into the queue

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
bool check(int a , int b , string s){
    int test[a][b];
    int k = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < b ; ++i){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < a ; ++j){
            test[i][j] = s[k++];
        }
    }

    bool f = true;
    bool fx = false;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < b ; ++i){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < a ; ++j){
            if(test[j][i] == 'O'){
                f = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(f){
            fx = true;
            break;
        }
        f = true;
    }
    return fx;
}

int main(void){
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    string s;
    queue<int> qa;
    queue<int> qb;
    const int n = 12;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < t ; ++i){
        cin>>s;
        int cnt = 0;
        int a[6] = {1  , 2 , 3 ,4  ,6 , 12};
        int b[6] = {12 , 6 , 4 , 3 ,2 ,  1};

        for(int j = 0 ; j < 6 ; ++j){
            if(check(a[j] , b[j] , s)){
                ++cnt;
                qa.push(a[j]);
                qb.push(b[j]);
            }
        }
        cout<<cnt<<' ';
        while(!qa.empty() && !qb.empty()){
            cout<<qa.front() <<'x'<<qb.front()<<' ';
            qa.pop();
            qb.pop();
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use a debugger? What is wrong about it? What output do you expect and what output do you get?

Comment: Please don't  `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` its non standard

Comment: "int main(void)" - ditch the `void` - it is meaningful in C, not so in C++.

Comment: What's your input? Unless you input at least twelve characters, the program is undefined and may output anything (or nothing).

Comment: @JesperJuhl it is indeed a C practice that is totally unnecessary in C.  However, it's not meaningless because the standard ensures that `f(void)` is equivalent to `f()` for any function, including for main

Comment: @Christophe Fine, redundant/pointless/noise then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part

```
int test[a][b];
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < b ; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < a ; ++j)
    {
        test[i][j] = s[k++];
    }
}
```

you create test[a][b] but you acess until test[b][a]